# How to make nginx-gridfs properly use the result of regex location match

Tags: nginx, gridfs

In short, this doesn't work:

```
location ~* /grid/(.+)/ {
         gridfs filestore field=filename type=string root_collection=storage.$1;
}
```

This is using https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs

There are multiple problems with it. This is just an FYI, as I don't think it can be done with location regex, because of:

1. group is not processes, and $1 is being used verbatim as a "storage.$1" collection name
2. Somehow, probably in the C code, file name is picked up by stripping characters from the match, by removing exact number of characters that is specified in regex. Meaning, "/grid/(.+)/" is 10 characters long, and this is how many characters are stripped from the entire url (minus domain, obviously). I've tested this quite a bit (short from just going through C code), and this is what it's doing.

I'm assuming this can be still done with rewrite somehow or another nginx config.

As a last resort, I'll reach out to the project maintainer, but nginx's configuration is flexible enough, it seems, to work around the issues, as this works as advertized:

```
location ~* /grid/ABC/ {
         gridfs filestore field=filename type=string root_collection=storage.ABC;
}
```

Comment: Is there no answer for this question or is it something else? Seems like a workaround with nginx rewrite of some sort is possible, if somebody knows how to do it properly. I've gone another way, unfortunately, simply because of not being able to do this.